# Unpublish npmjs

Tags: node.js, npm

Hi i am trying to remove a package in npmjs.
From the console, this command does not work for me. There is another one or something is missing.

-> npm unpublish md-elyfg@1.0.0

and it just throws this at me

- npm ERR! code EOTP
  npm ERR! This operation requires a one-time password from your authenticator.
  npm ERR! You can provide a one-time password by passing --otp= to the command you ran.
  npm ERR! If you already provided a one-time password then it is likely that you either typoed
  npm ERR! it, or it timed out. Please try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\eliza\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-07T19_53_12_637Z-debug.log

and if I generate it in another way

-> npm unpublish package_md-elyfg@1.0.0

result

- package_md-elyfg@1.0.0

Comment: Did you try adding the `--otp` arg? I haven't seen that specific error, but it sounds like you may have set up 2FA on npmjs.com

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it requires a **two-factor Authentication**.

try with `npm unpublish package_md-elyfg@1.0.0 --otp=<you otp>`

If you have two-factor authentication enabled for writes, you will need to add a one-time password to the **unpublish** command, **--otp=123456** (where 123456 is the code from your authenticator app).

In reference to: [NPM DOCS](https://docs.npmjs.com/unpublishing-packages-from-the-registry)